# b = [0] * len(st) TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to create an algorithm that basically see the stocks list in the program (Not real stocks just the one inside program :D) and buy when stocks is at lowest and sell when it's at highest and tell me how much is the profit. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Here is my code:

```
from turtle import st

mxdiff = 0
buy = 0
sell = 0
a = []  # min array from left
b = [0] * len(st)  # max array from right
d = []  # difference array
minleft = st[0]
maxright = st[len(st) - 1]

for i in range(0, len(st)):
    if (st[i] < minleft):
        minleft = st[i]
        a.append(st[i])
    else:
        a.append(minleft)

for i in range(len(st) - 1, -1, -1):
    if (st[i] > maxright):
        maxright = st[i]
        b[i] = st[i]
    else:
        b[i] = maxright

for i in range(0, len(st)):
    d.append(b[i] - a[i])

mxdiff = max(d)

for i in range(0, len(st)):
    if (d[i] == mxdiff and d[i + 1] == mxdiff):
        buy = i
        break

for i in range(len(st) - 1, -1, -1):
    if (d[i] == mxdiff and d[i - 1] == mxdiff):
        sell = i
        break

print("stocks has to be bought on day ")
print(buy + 1)

print("stocks has to be sold on day ")
print(sell + 1)
```

Comment: Well, it turns out that `turtle.st` is a function. So you can't meaningfully write `len(st)`. What did you think `st` was?

Comment: I think you first need to make some assumptions, you cant just create an algorithm that fits all possible scenarios in one shot

Answer (score -1):

.st() (.showturtle) is a function of the turtle module. Use some other variable and try.